# How do I correctly draw a video thumbnail on a canvas on all browsers?

Tags: javascript, canvas, exif, video-thumbnails

I have the following function that is able to generate a thumbnail from a video:

```js
async function getThumbnailForVideo(videoUrl) {
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  video.style.display = "none";
  canvas.style.display = "none";

  // Trigger video load
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
      video.width = video.videoWidth;
      video.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      // Seek the video to 25%
      video.currentTime = video.duration * 0.25;
    });
    video.addEventListener("seeked", () => resolve());
    video.src = videoUrl;
  });

  // Draw the thumbnail
  canvas
    .getContext("2d")
    .drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  const imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return imageUrl;
}
```

Paired with `URL.createObjectURL`, I am able to generate a thumbnail from a user-selected video file. I have created the following test project on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for testing: [App Editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/generate-video-file-thumbnail) [App Preview](https://generate-video-file-thumbnail.stackblitz.io)

While this seems to work fine for Chrome and Safari, it seems that Firefox does not respect the EXIF information of a video and as such draws it incorrectly.

The [MDN documentation for CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) explicitly states that:

> `drawImage()` will ignore all EXIF metadata in images, including the Orientation.. You should detect the Orientation yourself and use rotate() to make it right.

[Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) hints at a solution via its [exiforientation feature detection](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/exif-orientation.js) should I be able to read the rotation data from the file such that I only need to perform the extra transformations on Firefox.

I'm curious, is there a more idempotent solution to drawing an image from a `HTMLVideoElement` on all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the Modernizr `exiforientation` test only checks if an `img` element respects the EXIF data of an image, but not if the same image drawn onto a canvas is rendered correctly.

I set out instead to create my own test by drawing a known video on the canvas and testing it. I created the video as so using `ffmpeg`:

```sh
ffmpeg -filter_complex \
        "color=color=#ffffff:duration=1us:size=4x4[bg]; \
         color=color=#ff0000:duration=1us:size=2x2[r]; \
         color=color=#00ff00:duration=1us:size=2x2[g]; \
         color=color=#0000ff:duration=1us:size=2x2[b]; \
         [bg][r]overlay=x=2:y=0:format=rgb:alpha=premultiplied[bg+r]; \
         [bg+r][g]overlay=x=0:y=2:format=rgb:alpha=premultiplied[bg+r+g]; \
         [bg+r+g][b]overlay=x=2:y=2:format=rgb:alpha=premultiplied[bg+r+g+b]" \
       -map "[bg+r+g+b]" \
       -y wrgb-0.mp4

ffmpeg -i wrgb-0.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=180 -y wrgb-180.mp4
```

Using [the same demo](https://generate-video-file-thumbnail.stackblitz.io/), I can see that Chrome and Firefox generate different video previews on the canvas.

- Chrome: [image: wrgb-180 preview on Chrome], blue, green, red, white
- Firefox: [image: wrgb-180 preview on Firefox], white, red, green, blue

Next, I just needed a function such that given an array of RGBA values from the canvas it would spit out the pattern on the canvas:

```js
function getColourPattern(rgbaData) {
  let pattern = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < rgbaData.length; i += 4) {
    const r = rgbaData[i] / 255;
    const g = rgbaData[i + 1] / 255;
    const b = rgbaData[i + 2] / 255;
    const w = (r + g + b) / 3;

    if (w > 0.9) {
      pattern += "w";
      continue;
    }

    switch (Math.max(r, g, b)) {
      case r:
        pattern += "r";
        break;
      case g:
        pattern += "g";
        break;
      case b:
        pattern += "b";
        break;
    }
  }

  return pattern;
}
```

This returns `bbggbbggrrwwrrww` on Chrome & Safari, and `wwrrwwrrggbbggbb` on Firefox (with canvas fingerprinting turned off)

I then used `basenc --base64 wrgb-180.mp4 -w 0` to get a base64 representation of the video so that I could embed it into a single test function:

```js
export async function canvasUsesEXIF() {
  const videoUrl = `data:video/mp4;base64,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`;
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  video.style.display = "none";
  canvas.style.display = "none";

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    video.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
      video.width = video.videoWidth;
      video.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      video.currentTime = 0;
    });
    video.addEventListener("seeked", () => resolve());
    video.src = videoUrl;
  });

  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  const { data } = context.getImageData(0, 0, 4, 4);

  return getColourPattern(data) === "bbggbbggrrwwrrww";
}
```

Now assuming you have the rotation metadata of the video, you should be able to test if you need to rotate it on the canvas manually

**Edit 1**:

This should fix Firefox on Windows from throwing a `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE` error.

```
9c9
<     video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
---
>     video.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
```

Comment: This works like a charm at Chrome on Windows, but Chrome running on Android throws a video error: PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: video decoder reinitialization failed

Comment: @BrunoMarotta perhaps you could try using a different video? On Firefox for Android and Windows I did run into a separate issue that was fixed by replacing `loadedmetadata` with `canplay`.